# Does anyone know how to send cookies with express 4?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

It seems that express 4 has unbundled cookieparser, so I included it as it details in the docs, but res.cookie() doesn't seem to send the cookie anymore.

I have

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
```

followed by

```
res.cookie("token",tokval, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false });
```

but document.cookie returns nothing.

Express docs: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies

Any thoughts or suggestions (or prayers I suppose) would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You won't see [HttpOnly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) cookies in the browser. They are cookies that are automatically sent by the browser but unavailable to scripts on the page.

Comment: I have tried both ways - neither works. Please remove your downvote to avoid this post being lost since it is now updated to reflect httponly: false.